# Create openCV VideoCapture from interface name instead of camera numbers

Tags: python, opencv, interface, udev

The normal way to create a videocapture is this:

`cam = cv2.VideoCapture(n)`

where n corresponds to the number of `/dev/video0`, `dev/video1`

But because I'm building a robot that uses multiple cameras for different things, I needed to make sure that it was being assigned to the correct camera, I created udev rules that created devices with symbolic links to the correct port whenever a specific camera was plugged in.

They appear to be working because when I look in the `/dev` directory I can see the link:

`/dev/front_cam -> video1`

However I'm not sure how to actually use this now.

I thought I could just open it from the filename, as if it was a video, but `cam = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/front_cam')`  doesn't work.

Neither does `cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video1')`

It doesn't throw an error, it does return a VideoCapture object, just not one that's opened (`cam.isOpened()` returns `False`).

Comment: can you read the symbolic link from your program so that you can get the string '/dev/video1' programmatically? If yes, can you extract the number from that string (1) and feed it to your openCV capture object?

Comment: I upvoted your question, nice question I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
import subprocess
import cv2
import os

device_re = re.compile("Bus\s+(?P<bus>\d+)\s+Device\s+(?P<device>\d+).+ID\s(?P<id>\w+:\w+)\s(?P<tag>.+)$", re.I)
df = subprocess.check_output("lsusb", shell=True)
for i in df.split('\n'):
    if i:
        info = device_re.match(i)
        if info:
            dinfo = info.groupdict()
            if "Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270" in dinfo['tag']:
                print "Camera found."
                bus = dinfo['bus']
                device = dinfo['device']
                break

device_index = None
for file in os.listdir("/sys/class/video4linux"):
    real_file = os.path.realpath("/sys/class/video4linux/" + file)
    print real_file
    print "/" + str(bus[-1]) + "-" + str(device[-1]) + "/"
    if "/" + str(bus[-1]) + "-" + str(device[-1]) + "/" in real_file:
        device_index = real_file[-1]
        print "Hurray, device index is " + str(device_index)


camera = cv2.VideoCapture(int(device_index))

while True:
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read() # Grab the first frame
    cv2.imshow("Camera", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

First search for desired string in USB devices list. Get BUS and DEVICE number.

Find symbolic link under video4linux directory. Extract device index from realpath and pass it to VideoCapture method.

Answer (score 8):

Each of my video4linux devices creates 2 device nodes. For example, `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1` are both related to my internal webcam. When I plug in a second USB webcam, `/dev/video2` and `/dev/video3` both appear. However, I can only use the lower-numbered device of each pair for video capture (i.e. `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video2`).

I watched my device arrival with `udevadm monitor`, and then inspected each of the camera devices with `udevadm info --path=$PATH_FROM_UDEVADM_MONITOR --attribute-walk`. The devices which work for video capture have `ATTR{index}=="0"`.

Maybe instead of trying to open `/dev/video1`, you just need to open `/dev/video0`:

```
cam = cv2.CaptureVideo("/dev/video0")
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the suggested solution I found a shorter one, that feels a little bit hacky.

I just look at where the symbolic link points, find the integer in it, and then use that.

```
import subprocess

cmd = "readlink -f /dev/CAMC"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# output of form /dev/videoX
out = process.communicate()[0]

# parse for ints
nums = [int(x) for x in out if x.isdigit()]

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(nums[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the model of the camera, you can look it up in `/dev/v4l/by-id/...`. We are using an HDMI-USB video converter, and we connect to it like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os
import re
import cv2

DEFAULT_CAMERA_NAME = '/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-AVerMedia_Technologies__Inc._Live_Gamer_Portable_2_Plus_5500114600612-video-index0'

device_num = 0
if os.path.exists(DEFAULT_CAMERA_NAME):
    device_path = os.path.realpath(DEFAULT_CAMERA_NAME)
    device_re = re.compile("\/dev\/video(\d+)")
    info = device_re.match(device_path)
    if info:
        device_num = int(info.group(1))
        print("Using default video capture device on /dev/video" + str(device_num))
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(device_num)
```

This follows the device name symlink to the `/dev/video` name, then parses that for the device number.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility that was not explored in the other answers is to use the "name" file in the /sys/class/video4linux/video*/ directories.

Example :

```
def get_camera(camera_name):
    cam_num = None
    for file in os.listdir("/sys/class/video4linux"):
        real_file = os.path.realpath("/sys/class/video4linux/" + file + "/name")
        with open(real_file, "rt") as name_file:
            name = name_file.read().rstrip()
        if camera_name in name:
            cam_num = int(re.search("\d+$", file).group(0))
            found = "FOUND!"
        else:
            found = "      "
        print("{} {} -> {}".format(found, file, name))
    return cam_num
```

Which gives :

```
get_camera('HUE')
FOUND! video1 -> HUE HD Pro Camera: HUE HD Pro C
    video0 -> HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera
```