# Identify different cameras using OpenCV VideoCapture in Python

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I connected two USB cameras to my system (one RGB and another NIR).

One camera works on RGB and another on a grey scale, so they have a different channel.

I see that some people have suggested searching the camera IDs in the folder /dev/v4l/by-id/* and then opening the cameras as

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture('/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-e-con_systems_See3CAM_CU81_3233D508-video-index1')
```

I see that this example has been suggested in C++ code, and it's not working on Python.

Any suggestion on how I can identify the cameras and open them using VideoCapture in Python?

My camera list are:

```
ls /dev/v4l/by-id
usb-e-con_systems_See3CAM_CU27_192C8902-video-index0
usb-e-con_systems_See3CAM_CU27_192C8902-video-index1
usb-e-con_systems_See3CAM_CU81_3233D508-video-index0
usb-e-con_systems_See3CAM_CU81_3233D508-video-index1
```

Comment: If you add `-l` at the end of the command, you can see that these are actually symbolic links (shortcuts) to devices located in `/dev/`.
I'm not sure but maybe replacing the actual path of devices solves your problem.

Comment: Oh, and another thing, maybe you have to use device node `0` for each device. as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58650437/17588005